# Dovecot not downloading mail from mbox

Tags: dovecot, imap

I'm setting up Dovecot for the first time and cannot get the mail to download from the mbox file. I've turned on debugging and can see that Dovecot is pointed at the right place but still no mail will be parsed from the mbox file.

The first thing is that I do not want to have to create a home dir for each and every email user. I have a home directory but that's the only one that I want on the system.

Here is what I have currently:

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/%u/Maildir
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Where did you actually place the email? in `/home/username/Maildir` or `/var/mail/username`. See [this page](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox) for reference.

Comment: The email is in /var/mail. Thank you for the reference link, I'll have a look now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do something like that:

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/mail/%d/%n
```

For each your domain a folder will be created. Then subfolders named after users will be created. Immediately after username maildir structure begins.

That allows you to have different mailboxes for users with the same names but from different domains. Also you can easily backup what you want - `/home/mail/*` or `/home/mail/some.domain.com/*` or `/home/mail/some.domain.com/someuser/*`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to work well. Thank you again.